# Pragraph outside div changes position of paragraph inside div

Tags: html, css

i got the following html:

```
<div id="noiseCanvasDiv">
            <p>Noise</p>
            <canvas id="noiseCanvas" ></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="noiseLegend">
            <p class="legendOne">Blue Sensor</p><p class="legendTwo">Grey Sensor</p>
        </div>
        <div id="lightCanvasDiv">
            <p>Light</p>
            <canvas id="lightCanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
...
</div>
```

with the corresponding css:

```
baseCanvas,
#noiseCanvas,
#lightCanvas,
#activityCanvas {
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 310px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#noiseCanvas {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

#activityCanvas {
    float: left;
}

#noiseLegend {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

legendBaseclass,
.legendOne,
.legendTwo {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The paragraph `Light` should be displayed in the middle of the page like `Noise` does. But as soon as I add the `noiseLegend` it get's pushed to the left. How is this possible since it's surrounded by `lightCanvasDiv`?

[image]

Comment: why i dont see noise in middle with this code m i not getting you?

Comment: "Noise" is in the center of the page - why is "Light" pushed to the left?

Comment: put this code of yours in fiddle and see where is "Noise" http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `p{text-align:center}` make p text in center.

Comment: I'm guessing "Blue SensorGrey Sensor" does `float: left;`. Include a clearfix or make it a non floating block element with `text-algin: right;` or wrap it.

Comment: a damn - i totally forgot about the float! thanks @AlexG!

Comment: I'm glad :) I've posted the comment also as answer, though i noticed it actually floats right. dumb me x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From comments:*

> I'm guessing "Blue SensorGrey Sensor" does `float: right;`. Include a clearfix or make it a non floating block element with `text-algin: right;` or wrap it.